# Is there a way around regex grouping with an "or" statement?

Tags: java, regex

I read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) tutorial on regular expressions. I tried out using `|` (or) with groups. (Marked by parenthesis `()`), like so:

```
add (\\d+) to (\\d+)|(\\d+) plus (\\d+)
```

Examples of matching text being "add 5 to 6", or "5 plus 6".

However, the second option "5 plus 6", uses groups 3 and 4, because it is part of the same pattern. **Is it possible to "exclude" the groups before it if the second option matches?**

Code demonstrating said problem:

```
package example.regex.tester;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SmartMath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String textToMatch = "5 + 6";

        Pattern add = Pattern.compile("add (\\d+) to (\\d+)|(\\d+) plus (\\d+)");

        Matcher additionMatcher = add.matcher(query);

        if (additionMatcher.matches() == true) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(additionMatcher.group(1)); // Does not work because groups are numbered as 3 and 4 when "5 plus 6" is used.
            int b = Integer.parseInt(additionMatcher.group(2));

            System.out.println(a + b);

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Text does not match.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can always check for the presence of group 1 and 2, or group 3 and 4, before deciding which ones to parse...

Comment: Whenever unsure and willing to go to stack I go to http://www.regexr.com first, at the very least it will improve your testing speed.

Comment: You can only do that in [.NET with named capturing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression). Not in Java. You need to re-write the regex, like `(?:add )?(\\d+) (?:to|plus) (\\d+)`

Comment: What @stribizhev said. But to be sure that you will not end up with `add 123 plus 321` you can use look-ahead and test if string after it is in form `add \\d+ to \\d+|\\d+ plus \\d+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do that in .NET with [named capturing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression), not in Java.

You need to re-write the regex, so that it only has 2 groups. E.g.

```
(?:add )?(\\d+) (?:to|plus) (\\d+)
```

`(?:add )?` is optional, then we match a space, then 1 or more digits, then either "to" or "plus", then a space, and again 1 or more digits.

Comment: ...I was about to comment about how this didn't deserve to be accepted, since it was about .NET, not Java, and then I read the answer. Very creative solution!

Comment: I am not sure if this solves OP problem correctly since it looks like correct strings should be in form `add (\\d+) to (\\d+)` or `(\\d+) plus (\\d+)` not `add (\\d+) plus (\\d+)`.